# Write to Directshow source filter

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, opencv, directshow

I have got a directshow source filter which is based on http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads/vcam.zip. I want to write the webcam frames that has been manipulated using opencv by my (separate) application, to this virtual webcam (Directshow filter). How can I do this?

Any helpful code snippets please?

Comment: There are tens - if not hundreds - of topics on VCam sample. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created a custom interface in the Filters.h. Now I want to query this interface in my application and call the function inside this interface that sets the image data in Filters.cpp. So far custom interface is the best solution I came cross. But I am not sure how to query for this interface in my application which has been compiled using mingw. I am not sure if it is possible to do so.

Comment: The task is too broad. You have to take into account a lot of things, interprocess communication at the very least. `VCam` would be a tiny part of the thing you are describing. See this topic on a similar question http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/2e927f23-9062-4577-aef1-7cbd096612fe/

Answer (score 2):

A good practice for manipulating frames in Directshow is adding a SampleGrabber filter after your source filter. [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The SampleGrabber purpose is to manipulate frames.

Comment: Thank you very much for your respond. I will have a look later because currently I am very busy something else. Thanks again.